# PDO , No devulve resultados

Tags: php, mysql

Hace tiempo que no toco mysql, por diversos motivos tuve que hacerlo
tengo un archivo de pruebas, cuando ejecuto mi consula en phpmyadmin funciona y devuelve datos, si coloco la consulta en un procedimeinto almacenado devuelve datos, pero no debo usar procededimiento almacenado, no se que hacer en el archivo de ejecutar, ahora que subo ahora removí los ? ,? y los remplace por el usuario y la contraseña pero aun asi sin resultados.

Agradeceria mucho su ayuda. de antemano gracias.

Archivo de la sesión

```
<?php 
include("conexion.php");
class Sesion
{
    function login($user, $password)
    {
        $newconex = new DataBase();

        $quo="  SELECT U._ID AS '_ID',  
                    TRIM(CONCAT(P.NOMBRE,' ',P.APELLIDO)) AS 'NOMBRE' 
                FROM `usuarios` U, `personas` P
                WHERE P._ID=U._ID_PERSONA 
                AND U.USUARIO='admin'
                AND U.`CONTRASEÑA`=SHA1('admin');"; 

        $parametros = array($user,$password);
        $resultado = $newconex->query($quo,$parametros);


        $newconex=null;
        if($resultado)
        {
            session_start();//inicia la sesion

            $_SESSION['UCREA'] =$resultado[0]['_ID'];
            $_SESSION['NOMBRE'] =$resultado[0]['NOMBRE'];               
            return 1;               
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}?>
```

Clase DB

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

    /* clase de base da datos */
    class DataBase {

        private $conexion = null;

        /* Construcctor */
        public function __construct()
        {
            $HOST = "localhost";
            $DBNAME = "test";
            $USERNAME = "root";
            $PASSWORD = "";
            try {
                $this->conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=".$HOST.";dbname=".$DBNAME, $USERNAME, $PASSWORD);
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

        public function desconectar() 
        {
            if($this->conexion != null) $this->conexion = null;
        }


        public function query($sql,$parametros)
        {
            $make = $this->conexion->prepare($sql);

            if(is_array($parametros))
            {
                $make->execute($parametros);                    
            }
            else
            {
                $make->execute();
            }       


            $result = $make->fetchall();
            $make->closeCursor();
            return $result;
        }

        public function query_exec($sql,$parametros)
        {
            $make = $this->conexion->prepare($sql);

            if(is_array($parametros))
            {
                $result = $make->execute($parametros);  
            }
            else
            {
                $result = $make->execute();
            }
            $make->closeCursor();
            return $result;
        }
    }
?>
```

Archivo de ejecución

```
<?php
    include("class/sesion.php");
    $sesion =new Sesion();
    echo  $sesion->login("admin","admin");
?>
```

Como anotaciones quiero destacar que si hago un select simple como

Select 'algo' as 'valor';

obtengo resultado, si elimino el where obtengo resultados...
si uso consulta en un procedimeinto almacenado obtengo resultados...
el detalles es que no puedo usarlo, porque es necesario que en php se vea el codigo

/////////// ANEXO PROCEDIMIENTO ALMACENADO

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE CHECK_SESION(IN username VARCHAR(255),IN userpassword VARCHAR(255))
 BEGIN

     SELECT U._ID AS '_ID', TRIM(CONCAT(P.NOMBRE,' ',P.APELLIDO)) AS 'NOMBRE' 
    FROM `usuarios` U, `personas` P
    WHERE P._ID=U._ID_PERSONA 
    AND U.USUARIO=username
    AND U.`CONTRASEÑA`=SHA1(userpassword);

 END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Discúlpame por el off-topic pero me hace ruido que abras una transacción solamente para hacer una consulta de datos.

Comment: Hola es muy sencillo, ocasiones he usado SQL server y PHP, cuando la consulta lleva ciertas funciones o varias tablas temporales, la consulta preparada no devuelve resultados, la solución es meterlo todo en una transacción y utilizar SET NOCOUNT ON.
Desgraciadamente estuve investigando y no existe algo similar en MYSQL, revisé y algunos proponían solamente utilizar transacciones.
Antes de preguntar probé muchas y diversas cosas, realmente considero que si bien es innecesario para una consulta tan simple, tenía que probarlo y quise dejarlo en el código para que vieran que probé eso tambien,

Comment: Si lees la documentacion oficial te darás cuenta que PDO maneja todo por vos. Lo digo por el tema de las transacciones y si tienes múltiples motores de base de datos.

Comment: Ya lei la documentación oficial,  con eso habia construido esa clase, aun asi le dare una leia nuevamente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si analizamos el codigo del storeProcedure:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT U._ID AS '_ID',  
  TRIM(CONCAT(P.NOMBRE,' ',P.APELLIDO)) AS 'NOMBRE' 
  FROM `usuarios` U, `personas` P
  WHERE P._ID=U._ID_PERSONA 
  AND U.USUARIO='admin'
  AND U.`CONTRASEÑA`=SHA1('admin');
IF @@error_count > 0 THEN
  ROLLBACK;
ELSE
  COMMIT;
END;
```

Podemos ver claramente que esta compuesta de un total de 3 acciones: iniciar trans. un select y dependiendo de si dio error o no, commit o rollback;

> Lo que intentas hacer no funcionara de igual manera, ya que no es la forma que lo deberias hacer.
>
> Cuando utilizas **[PDO](http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php)**, debes hacer uso de los metodos que provee.
>
> Tambien esta claro que es **totalmente innecesario iniciar una transaccion para un SELECT**

Una posible solución a tu problema utilizando **PDO**, seria la siguiente:

```
function login($user, $pass)
{
    $newconex = new DataBase();
    $query="SELECT U._ID AS _ID,
        TRIM(CONCAT(P.NOMBRE,' ',P.APELLIDO)) AS NOMBRE
      FROM usuarios U, personas P
      WHERE P._ID = U._ID_PERSONA 
        AND U.USUARIO = :user
        AND U.CONTRASEÑA = SHA1(:pass)"; 

    // las claves del arreglo deben empezar con :
    $params = array(
      ':user'=> $user,
      ':pass'=> $pass
    );

    // NOTA 1
    $res= $newconex->query($query,$params);
    $newconex=null;

    // Si no es FALSE y tiene exactamente 1 registro
    if($res && count($res) === 1) {
        session_start();//inicia la sesion

        $_SESSION['UCREA'] =$res[0]['_ID'];
        $_SESSION['NOMBRE'] =$res[0]['NOMBRE'];               
        return 1;               
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

> **NOTA 1**: [PDOStatement::fetchAll()](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchall.php) devuelve un array que contiene tadas las filas restantes del conjunto de resultados. Es devuelto un array vacío si hay cero resultados que obtener, o **FALSE en caso de fallo**.
>   (Personalmente yo devolveria PDOStatement en lugar del resultado del fetchAll)

Por ultimo, si llegaras a necesitar utilizar transacciones, te recomiendo veamos [PDO::beginTransaction](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.begintransaction.php), [PDO::commit](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.commit.php) y [PDO::rollBack](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.rollback.php)

**// UPDATE**

- Error: Las claves deben empezar con ":" (se me olvidaron)

  ```
  $params = array(
     ':user'=> $user,
     ':pass'=> $pass
  );
  ```
- Modificacion: Indica el charset a la DB (eg: ;charset=UTF8)

  ```
  $this->conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=".$HOST.";dbname=".$DBNAME.";charset=UTF8", $USERNAME, $PASSWORD);
  ```

> Para evitar problemas con caracteres especiales y comparaciones de cadenas, siempre es necesario indicar el **charset** en el DSN.

Comment: Acabo de añadir mi procedimeitno almacenado

Comment: haciendo vardump me devuelve array vacio usando la consulta simple sin las transacciones
Usando procedimeinto almacenado si devuelve datos

Comment: Entonces existen 2 posibilidades. 1) que no exista el usuario con esa contraseña. 2) Que algo en la consulta este mal. Prueba reemplazando en la consulta  :user y :pass, por el valor 'admin' y dime que te devuelve.

Comment: Me devuelve vacio

Comment: Podrías agregar el resultado que te devuelve el procedimiento almacenado?

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["_ID"]=> string(1) "1" [0]=> string(1) "1" ["NOMBRE"]=> string(15) "Profesor Prueba" [1]=> string(15) "Profesor Prueba" } } 1

Comment: Es la impresion del procedimeinto y con var_dump

Comment: array(0) { } 0 
Este es el resultado de la consulta

Comment: he actualizado mi respuesta

Comment: Ya lo habia compuesto antes lo de :

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48501/discussion-between-marcos-gallardo-and-darkeniel).

Answer (score 0):

Haber, el problema esta en que no has leído la documentacion oficial sobre lo que se debe hacer para que te funcione tu código. Vamos por partes...

```
// prepare() retorna un PDOStatement y lo asigna a $make.
$make = $this->conexion->prepare($sql);

[...]

// Si bien, completas correctamente el metodo execute(), debes realizar
// antes un par de procedimientos..
$make->execute($parametros);
```

En la documentacion oficial del método [execute()](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.execute.php) dice claramente:

> Si ésta incluía marcadores de parámetros, se debe:
>
> - llamar a PDOStatement::bindParam() y/o PDOStatement::bindValue() para
>     vincular variables o valores (respectivamente) a los marcadores de
>     parámetros. Las variables vinculadas pasan su valor como entrada y
>     reciben el valor de salida, si lo hubiera, de sus marcadores de
>     parámetros asociados
> - o pasar un array de valores de parámetros de sólo entrada

Lo que no encuentro en tu codigo es que *bindees* lo parametros. Si tu intencion fue querer pasar parametros, entonces tu error esta aca:

```
SELECT U._ID AS '_ID',  
TRIM(CONCAT(P.NOMBRE,' ',P.APELLIDO)) AS 'NOMBRE' 
FROM `usuarios` U, `personas` P
WHERE P._ID=U._ID_PERSONA 
AND U.USUARIO='admin' -- En vez de 'admin', deberia ser ':user'
AND U.`CONTRASEÑA`=SHA1('admin'); -- En vez de 'admin', deberia ser ':pass'
```

y cuando pases los valores por array, deberia ser un array asociativo. Algo como:

```
$parametros = array(
    ":user" => "AcaVaElValor",
    ":pass" => "AcaVaLaContrasenia"
);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php#112641
En la parte de arriba comento que remplace los ? por el usuario y la contraseña respectivamente. pero probare la forma segura , la consulta original deberia ser asi

Comment: $quo="START TRANSACTION;
                SELECT U._ID AS '_ID',  
                    TRIM(CONCAT(P.NOMBRE,' ',P.APELLIDO)) AS 'NOMBRE' 
                FROM `usuarios` U, `personas` P
                WHERE P._ID=U._ID_PERSONA 
                AND U.USUARIO=?
                AND U.`CONTRASEÑA`=SHA1(?);

            IF @@error_count > 0 THEN
               ROLLBACK;
            ELSE
              COMMIT;
            END; ";

Comment: Quiero agregar como anotacion que en prodecimiento almacenado si me funciona y pasa los parametros

pero es el mismo destino que con mi codigo actual

$quo="CALL CHECK_USER(?,?)";      
$parametros = array($user,$password);
$resultado = $newconex->query($quo,$parametros);

Comment: $quo="CALL CHECK_USER(:user,:pass)"
$parametros = array( ":user" => $user, ":pass" =>$password);
Pero sige si funciona si uso solo la consula

Answer (score 0):

Intenta revisando los datos que contiene la variable $resultado modificando tu codigo de la Clase Sesion:

```
<?php 
include("conexion.php");
class Sesion
{
    function login($user, $password)
    {
        $newconex = new DataBase();

        $quo="  SELECT U._ID AS '_ID',  
                    TRIM(CONCAT(P.NOMBRE,' ',P.APELLIDO)) AS 'NOMBRE' 
                FROM `usuarios` U, `personas` P
                WHERE P._ID=U._ID_PERSONA 
                AND U.USUARIO='admin'
                AND U.`CONTRASEÑA`=SHA1('admin');"; 

        $parametros = array($user,$password);
        $resultado = $newconex->query($quo,$parametros);

        echo"<pre>";
        print_r($resultado);
        echo"</pre>";
        die();

        $newconex=null;
        if($resultado)
        {
            session_start();//inicia la sesion

            $_SESSION['UCREA'] =$resultado[0]['_ID'];
            $_SESSION['NOMBRE'] =$resultado[0]['NOMBRE'];               
            return 1;               
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}?>
```

Si la variable $resultado está vacía, entonces cambia tu consulta por la siguiente, la cual debería traer todos los registros que estén en la tabla usuarios y personas:

```
$quo="  SELECT U._ID AS '_ID',  
        TRIM(CONCAT(P.NOMBRE,' ',P.APELLIDO)) AS 'NOMBRE' 
        FROM `usuarios` U, `personas` P
        WHERE P._ID=U._ID_PERSONA;";
```

Si obtienes datos con esta modificación, podría ser que el problema esté en como fue encriptada la contraseña al ingresarla a la base de datos.